# Python: Even after specifying delimiter, csv writer delimits at wrong place

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write lists like this to a CSV file:

```
['ABC','One,Two','12']
['DSE','Five,Two','52']
```

To a file like this:

```
ABC   One,Two   12
DSE   Five,Two   52
```

Basically, write anything inside '' to a cell. 
However, it is splitting One and Two into different cells and merging ABC with One in the first cell.

Part of my script:

```
out_file_handle = open(output_path, "ab")
writer = csv.writer(out_file_handle, delimiter = "\t", dialect='excel', lineterminator='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)    
output_final = (tsv_name_list.split(".")[0]+"\t"+key + "\t" + str(listOfThings))
output_final = str([output_final]).replace("[","").replace("]","").replace('"',"").replace("'","")
output_final = output_final.split("\\t")
print output_final #gives the first lists of strings I mentioned above.
writer.writerow(output_final)
```

First output_final line gives

```
ABC  One,Two  12
DSE  Five,Two  52
```

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Yes. But the csv file has ABC\tOne in a cell, Two\t12 in another cell, which is not what I'm trying to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `csv` module simply works, so you're going to need to be more specific about what's convincing you that the elements are bleeding across cells.  For example, using the (now quite outdated) Python 2.7:

```
import csv

data_lists = [['ABC','One,Two','12'],
              ['DSE','Five,Two','52']]

with open("out.tsv", "wb") as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter="\t", dialect="excel", lineterminator="\n")
    writer.writerows(data_lists)
```

I get an `out.tsv` file of:

```
dsm@winter:~/coding$ more out.tsv 
ABC One,Two 12
DSE Five,Two    52
```

or

```
>>> out = open("out.tsv").readlines()
>>> for row in out: print repr(row)
... 
'ABC\tOne,Two\t12\n'
'DSE\tFive,Two\t52\n'
```

which is exactly as it should be.  Now if you take these rows, which are tab-delimited, and for some reason split them using *commas* as the delimiter, sure, you'll think that there are two columns, one with `ABC\tOne` and one with `Two\t12`.  But that would be silly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What can I do if I want a .csv instead of .tsv with tab delimiter?

Comment: @pam: don't set `delimiter="\t"`, which tells it to use a tab as a delimiter. :-)  Note that if you do that, you'll want to remove your `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`, because if you want to use commas as delimiters but also have commas in the values, you'll need to make sure it automatically quotes them so you can split it correctly later.

Comment: For some reason `delimiter="\t"` needs the double quotes. Single quotes did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You've set up the CSV writer, but then for some reason you completely ignore it and try to output the lines manually. That's pointless. Use the functionality available.

```
writer = csv.writer(...)
for row in tsv_list:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It says `AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'write'`. When I do writer.writerow, it gives ABC\tOne in a cell, Two\t12 in another.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "cell" though. Are you perhaps importing into Excel but using a comma-delimited format rather than a tab-delimited one?